# Windows in asyncore, asynchat

Tags: python, python-2.7, asyncore

I am trying to create an chat program using python in mac os x python 2.7.5.

I have successfully done so using the asyncore, asynchat modules however. I create a server that will open a telnet port on say 5006. Which is fine.

Here is the problem That previously mentioned executable creates a window in terminal now when I want to actually start chatting I have to open another terminal window and type $ telnet 127.0.0.1 5006 to open a connection to myself. Others have to do the same thing from their respective computers.

BUT I only want to open one window that will run my server code and chat with others.

I just want to make clear. There is no problem here with chatting and connections I am asking how to reduce my 2 window server/chatter to a server and chatter in one.

I dont need anybody to write my code I am looking for a push in the right direction if someone doesn't have a direct answer. Maybe a module of some sort or something similar. Im lost so...

Comment: this looks like you want to do something along the lines of `threading`, that way you can have the server code being run in one thread, and the client code being run in another thread.

Comment: threading, good suggestion thanks a lot and if you come up with something else please let me know

Comment: Terrible suggestion.  The OP has already mentioned the use of asyncore.  The whole point of asyncore is to multiplex I/O operations.  For example, to read from stdin concurrently with servicing network messages from other chat clients.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As stated in the comments above the answer is     threading